# SVG stroke width increasing issue

Tags: html, css, svg

i am in very starage issue about svg.
When the svg stroke is in a full state and the stroke width value increases, the stroke will gradually shrink.
please give me any idea.

below is full svg code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="spum50f8sl" x="0px" y="0px" width="461px" height="461px" viewBox="0 0 461 461" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" isInit="true" opacity="1" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <defs isInit="true">
    <clipPath isInit="true" id="spum50f8sloutlineclippath">
      <path d="M0,230.04000000000002A230.04000000000002,230.04000000000002,0,1,0,460.08000000000004,230.04000000000002A230.04000000000002,230.04000000000002,0,1,0,0,230.04000000000002Z" fill="#cacaca" origin_fill="#cacaca" isInit="true"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#spum50f8sloutlineclippath)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="500">
    <path d="M0,230.04000000000002A230.04000000000002,230.04000000000002,0,1,0,460.08000000000004,230.04000000000002A230.04000000000002,230.04000000000002,0,1,0,0,230.04000000000002Z" fill="#cacaca" origin_fill="#cacaca" isInit="true"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

below is stroke-width: 500
[image]
below is stroke-width: 800
[image: stroke-width: 100]

Comment: I think as the <path> is 460px width from its coodinates the stroke cannot take his 500px as requested. So the display of the complete svg is resized according to the viewBox definition. For exemple if you put exactly 460px in the stroke-width, the stroke takes the entire circle. But as soon you increase that value the resize starts.

Comment: As foxlab commented you can use a value for the stroke not bigger than 2*radius of the circle. In this case radius = 230.04 thus the stroke value should be smaller than 460.06

Comment: Like the above comments, there is nothing stopping you setting a stroke-width what is too wide for the shape. What is you goal? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: The precise rendering of a path whose stroke width is more than double of its radius is undefined – see the note in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#StrokeShape). You may see the behavior you describe in one browser/renderer, but others may do it differently. @Foxlab that has nothing to do with the viewBox or scaling. No resizing is happening.

Comment: @ccprog I can not find specificaition about stroke width is more than double of its radius is undefined. where is it?

Comment: Exactly. That case is not handled. All the spec has to say is the warning text in the green box: "Authors should be aware that the shape of a stroke may in some cases, such as at extremely tight curves, differ across platforms. "